# How can I be sure that List.Contains works for a list of DataTables?

Tags: c#, list, datatable, comparison

If I have this:

```
 List<DataTable> listDataTables = functionToAddSomeDataTables();
```

and I want to do a comparison like this:

```
if(listDataTables.Contains(aDataTable))
{
   //do something.
}
```

How can I know if it is comparing the reference or the schema or the content or all of the above?

Do I need to write my own IEquatable.Equals to make sure it works properly or can I trust that the built in .Equals for DataTable works as I would hope?

Is there a general rule or observation for knowing when .Contains, or similar comparisons  are by reference or by value?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>.Contains` uses the object's `object.Equals(object)` method. Since [`DataTable`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) says that its `Equals` was inherited from `Object.Equals`, the default `Object.Equals` implementation of reference comparison is what will be used. If you want the comparison by something else, include that equality comparer by using LINQ's [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

(as an example, compare [DataTable Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Decimal Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Decimal_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): only `Decimal` lists `Equals` on the list on the left, and says "(Overrides ValueType.Equals(Object).)" instead of "(Inherited from Object.)")

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own Equals method and compare the needed properties where. The built in (default) Contains() method will check values for value types (string, int...) and references for reference types (your class is a reference type)